# docker and rootless docker side-by-side - is it allowed?

Tags: docker

Does anyone know if running docker and rootless docker at the same time can cause any issues?

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#install) says:

```
If the system-wide Docker daemon is already running, consider disabling it
```

But they don't say why should we consider disabling it.

When installing rootless docker when docker is running the following error is shown:

```
[ERROR] Aborting because rootful Docker (/var/run/docker.sock) is running and accessible. Set --force to ignore.
```

So we can ignore it. But is it safe to do so?
Is it allowed to run them side be side, or not allowed?

Answer (score 3):

At least on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with Docker CE 23.0.2 it is absolutely no problem to run Docker and rootless Docker side-by-side.

Despite any notes in the documentation, `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install` does not show an error message. Instead it adds a new [Docker Context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) "rootless" and sets it as the default.

Now I can access Docker with `docker -c default` and rootless Docker is set as default for `docker`.